# Rectangles in StackPanel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, stackpanel, rectangles

I'm trying to insert multiple rectangles in a stackpanel but I keep getting the error 'Element is already the child of another element.'. Same thing happens if I use a canvas.

Example:

```
List<Rectangle> recList = new List<Rectangle>();
```

...put some rectangles in the list

```
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();

foreach(var item in recList)
     stack.Children.Add(item); // get error here on 2nd item trying to add

uiStackPanel.Children.Add(stack); // declared in XAML
```

I want to be able to insert rectangles dynamically in a horizontal orientation.
According to the Internet I should be able to do this (manually at least) but...

What to do, what to do? :)

Comment: Can you show the code that populates the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are adding the same rectangle more than once.

If you need to add different rectangles than the code would be like this:

```
var list = new List<Rectangle>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Rectangle());
}

var panel = new StackPanel();
foreach (var rectangle in list)
{
    panel.Children.Add(rectangle);
}
```

This code works.

Comment: Hi there @Alex Aza
Thank you, that did it!

Comment: @viktorb - Hi viktorb. If Alex's answer worked for you, then you can mark it as an answer so that it's clear to everyone else that your question has been solved :)